# VSCode Output Not Scrollable Window for Plots

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter, you can have a scrollable output window after it exceeds some height. I have been able to replicate this using *only* text in VSCode, but cannot get it to work for matplotlib plots. I attached a gif to demonstrate the issue. I would like the output containing the plots to become a scrollable window like the text does. If I combine text and plot output, the issue persists.
[image: Text can be scrollable output window while plots cannot]

I have tried searching the internet laboriously. I have changed the notebook textLineLimit to its minimum value (1) and that did not fix things -- it only made the scrollable window much smaller for text output (as expected).

Comment: can you take a look at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26465, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140148 and see if either match your problem or help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these help. I'm not trying to save the output, and the plots are not being cropped. If I display multiple plots in a single output cell, I'd just like to make it into a scrollable window, like what happens in Jupyter (and like what happens with the text in the gif).